# Creating a tracking table in Codeigniter. Inserting data with Foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, loops, cron

I want to create a tracking table to monitor follower count of a project every day. The table will be updated every 24 hours.

The outcome will look something like this: [Instagram followers Growth Line Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPk8T.png)

I have two tables right now. One for Projects and one for Twitter Tracking.

I want to get the data from the Projects table (Project ID, Twitter URL), turn the data into variables ($ico_id, $twitter_url), parse the followers count from Twitter, and then insert everything into a Twitter Tracking table. And the insert has to be executed for every project. In the end, I should have around 270 results every day.

I have managed to insert information about a single project using foreach(), but it only took the first row, and then stopped.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Tracker_model extends CI_Model {
    #insert follower count 
    public function twitter_followers(){
        $query = $this->db->get('icos');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $ico_id = $row->id;
                $twitter_url = $row->twitter;

                $page = @file_get_contents($twitter_url);
                $followers = @explode("followers_count&quot;:", explode(",&quot;friends_count", $page)[0])[1];  

                $data = array (
                    'ico_id'      => $ico_id,
                    'twitter_url' => $twitter_url,
                    'year'        => date("Y"),
                    'month'       => date("m"),
                    'month_word'  => date("F"),
                    'day'         => date("d"),
                    'day_word'    => date("l"),
                    'week'        => date("W"),
                    'followers'   => $followers
                );

                $insert_followers = $this->db->insert('twitter_followers', $data);
                return $insert_followers;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

And this is the result:
[MySQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXqaJ.png)
The code (model) should be executed every 24 hours and I will use cron for this. 
Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because `return` statement. It will terminate your loop so only first record will be inserted. Remove this return statement. Then execute your code:

```
<?php
class Tracker_model extends CI_Model {
    #insert follower count 
    public function twitter_followers(){
        $query = $this->db->get('icos');
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($query->result() as $row) {
                $ico_id = $row->id;
                $twitter_url = $row->twitter;

                $page = @file_get_contents($twitter_url);
                $followers = @explode("followers_count&quot;:", explode(",&quot;friends_count", $page)[0])[1];  

                $data = array (
                    'ico_id'      => $ico_id,
                    'twitter_url' => $twitter_url,
                    'year'        => date("Y"),
                    'month'       => date("m"),
                    'month_word'  => date("F"),
                    'day'         => date("d"),
                    'day_word'    => date("l"),
                    'week'        => date("W"),
                    'followers'   => $followers
                );

                $insert_followers = $this->db->insert('twitter_followers', $data);               
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake! Thank you for pointing it out. Also, is tracking done in a similar way (talking about real-world applications)? Or will this work ok?